# Have multiple if (isset($_POST["submit"])) on one page

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I have the code below on my page twice.

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
 // ...
}
```

How can I separate them? E.G.:

```
if (isset($_POST["#form1"])) {
 // code
}
if (isset($_POST["#form2"])) {
 // code
}
```

I know that doesn't work, but it's an example if what I want to make

Comment: You can give your different submit buttons different names or check for uniquely named elements in the different forms instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment below, its better to have a named submit button element within the form.

```
<form name="form" action="<?php echo __FILE__ ?>" method="POST">
  <input name="form1" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<?php
  if(isset($_POST['form1'])){ 
    var_dump($_POST);
  }
?>
```

Since I've been using nothing but ajax requests I didn't really run into the issue but using a name in the form is possible using jQuery as well.

However I'm quite sure there are mutliple answers spread around stackoverflow so next time search a little bit better.

Comment: name should be on submit input, not on the form itself..

Comment: named forms do work @Reloecc but only if jQuery is used.

Comment: Updated my answer, thanks for the quick and usefull comments

Comment: This doesn't work out for us for some reason..

Comment: NVM, I didn't add the `name="formname"` to the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<form name="form1" action="/url" method="POST">

</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST["form1"])) {
 // ...
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how and why it solves the problem and doesn’t introduce others.